# Why do some players sometimes get double the amount of money after a mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Sometimes, some players get double the amount of money after a mission in GTA 5 online. What affects this amount of money? Is it randomly doubled? Or do I only get the doubled amount if I haven't played that mission ever before? And if I ever replay it, I only get the regular amount (respectively half the amount you get in comparison to the first time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read that you get **1.5-2x more money** than usual **the first time you complete a job**. If you replay the job you'll get a smaller payout. The players you're seeing with a bigger payout have likely just completed that particular job for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You do get double the amount first time you complete a mission.  I have also heard many times of people getting double the amount just randomly, but I strongly suspect this is just a bug rather than something that can be triggered somehow.